# understanding domain.withNewSession in grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I have a simple domain class

```
package cat

class Cat {

    String name

    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

I read that the withNewSession will open a new session so it doesn't use the cached result of any previous query. It forces the system to re-query from the database. So, i am writing few simple test code to understand the behavior of withNewSession.

First of all i save a cat with name "tom" so in the database i have one cat record of name "tom". Now i write the following code to understand withNewSession

```
import cat.*

def cc = Cat.get(1)

cc.name = "sylvester"

Cat.withNewSession{session ->

  println cc.name

}
```

In the above code, i first get the cat with name "tom" from database. Then, i change the name to "sylvester". Then i start a new session and inside it query the name of the fetched cat. My assumption was that the system would re-query from the database since the new session has a blank new cache so re-querying from the database would fetch the unmodified cat instance. But the name printed is the modified one i.e "sylvester". So, i have doubts understanding the behavior of withNewSession. Can someone clear my doubts maybe by providing a better simple working example that shows the behavior of withNewSession? I appreciate your help very much! Thank you!

Comment: Cat is an object, and there's nothing particularly special about the `name` property. Calling `cc.name` doesn't query the database with or without a new session - if it did, GORM would be insanely expensive. The only time that would trigger a call to the database would be if the `Cat` instance was an uninitialized Hibernate proxy where any property set or get will trigger a database load for all of the properties, but once initialized there would be no further per-property db access. But this isn't a proxy, so that's not a factor.

Comment: when would one want to wrap a code block inside a withNewSession? can you give an example?

Comment: The most obvious example is when you are not inside a request and a session was not opened automatically for you. withSession would fail because there is no session and you need to open one explicitly.

Comment: I suppose there are edge conditions where you would want to avoid the Hibernate caches, e.g. you are in the middle of a calculation and would like to query the uncommited state (or perhapse avoid an implicit flush), but for these cases I would say you will recognize them when you need them :)

Comment: @GregorPetrin can you provide a simple example using withNewSession. I appreciate it!

Comment: ok I am posting my own answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32328150/understanding-withnewsession-in-grails/39844612#39844612